# Using timestamp with time zone with Npgsql

Tags: c#, .net, database, npgsql, postgresql-9.2

There is a need to save timestamp with time zone in database. Target field in table is declared as

```
"UploadTime" timestamp with time zone
```

I'm inserting data using command parameters :

```
var uploadTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
var insertQuery = @"INSERT INTO ""Table"" (""UploadTime"") VALUES :uploadTime"; 
var uploadTimeParam = new NpgsqlParameter("uploadTime", NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTZ);
uploadTimeParam.Value = uploadTime;
var insertCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(insertQuery, databaseConnection);
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(uploadTimeParam);
```

Value is stored and returned as DateTime without time zone. I guess that's because "timestamp with timezone" database type is mapped to DateTime by default. Probably that can be fixed via checking out sources and making respective changes to TimestampTZ, but it will interfere with idea of using Nuget to manage project dependencies. Maybe there are some less complicated ways to achieve that? Storing ticks and converting them to DateTimeOffset is an overhead, hack with "SET TIME ZONE INTERVAL" before query execution didn't work in my case. Thanks in advance for any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem via storing of additional timestamp RTT field which maps to DateTimeOffset manually.

Comment: please expand more explain

Comment: @MohsenZahedi It was long ago, but I think I've just added second field (UploadTimeRTT) for needed datetime that was converted to DateTimeOffset in the application code manually and maintained them both. Not very effective from the database schema design standpoint, but it worked.